# Posted jSon object is null when received in api controller

Tags: json, restsharp

I try to retrieve the model i sent as jSon using restSharp to my API controller, but the TestCard object is always null when I receive it in my controller, why is that?

**Model**

```
public class TestCard
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Adress { get; set; }
    public string Adress2 { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

**Test Post**

```
        var personList = new List<Person>();
        personList.Add(new Person
        {
            Name = "John Doe",
            Adress = "West Park Ave",
            PostalCode = "123",
            City = "NY",
            Country = "US"
        });
        personList.Add(new Person
        {
            Name = "Sandra Doe",
            Adress = "West Park Ave",
            PostalCode = "123",
            City = "NY",
            Country = "US"
        });
        var order = new TestCard() { OrderId = 1, Persons = personList };


        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        var client = new RestClient("https://localhost:44336/api/card/");
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("myusername", "mypassword");

        var request = new RestRequest("Add", Method.Post);

        request.AddBody(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(order));
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        Task<RestResponse> response = client.ExecuteAsync(request);
        if (response.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
        {
            Response.Write("OK!");
        }
```

**Controller**

```
    [Route("api/Card/Add")]
    [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Add([FromBody] TestCard model)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use request.addbody you don't have to serialize object

```
request.AddBody(order);
```

and IMHO , remove [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")] since you have already  [HttpPost]